# Syntax Error while creating a football player Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I was wondering if any of you would be able to assist. I'm fairly new to python and I'm getting a syntax error with this embedded list item:

```py
myDict = {
        "Date": "20210807",
        "KickOff": "15:00",
        "Result": "2-1",
        "Opposition": "Wigan",
        "Home/Away": "Home",
        "Player": 
            [   #syntax error on this line
                "Lee Burge": 
                    [
                        "Minutes Played": "90",
                        "Shirt Number": "1",
                        "Position": "G",
                        "Match Rating": "6.3",
                        "Captain": "N",
                        "Substitute": "N",
                        "Offsides": "0",
                        "Shot Total": "0",
                        "Shots On Target": "0",
                        "Goals": "0",
                        "Goals Conceded": "1",  
                        "Assists": "0",
                        "Saves": "2",
                        "Pass Total": "26",
                        "Key Passes": "0",
                        "Accurate Passes": "14",
                        "Pass Accuracy": "53.85",
                        "Tackles Total": "0",
                        "Blocks": 0,
                        "Interceptions": 0,
                        "Duels Total": 1,
                        "Duels Won": 0,
                        "Dribble Attempts": 0,
                        "Dribble Successful": 0,
                        "Dribble Past": 0,
                        "Fouls Drawn": 0,   
                        "Fouls Committed": 0,
                        "Red Card": 0,
                        "Yellow Card": 0,
                        "Penalties Won":    0,
                        "Penalties Committed": 0,
                        "Penalties Scored": 0,
                        "Penalties Missed": 0,
                        "Penalties Saved": 0
                    ]
            ]
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: You are trying to define a `dict` but you open with brackets (`[`) defining a list. Depending on what you want, replace `[` by `{`, or change the definition of your `"Player"` key.

Comment: provide the code that you are working with that gives you the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the point you marked as a syntax error, you open with a list but you are using dictionary syntax (by writing `"Lee Burge":`). I assume you actually want nested dictionaries:

```py
myDict = {
        "Date": "20210807",
        "KickOff": "15:00",
        "Result": "2-1",
        "Opposition": "Wigan",
        "Home/Away": "Home",
        "Player": 
            {   # Note that this is a dictionary now
                "Lee Burge": 
                    {   # Here, you also have a dictionary
                        "Minutes Played": "90",
                        "Shirt Number": "1",
                        "Position": "G",
                        "Match Rating": "6.3",
                        "Captain": "N",
                        "Substitute": "N",
                        "Offsides": "0",
                        "Shot Total": "0",
                        "Shots On Target": "0",
                        "Goals": "0",
                        "Goals Conceded": "1",  
                        "Assists": "0",
                        "Saves": "2",
                        "Pass Total": "26",
                        "Key Passes": "0",
                        "Accurate Passes": "14",
                        "Pass Accuracy": "53.85",
                        "Tackles Total": "0",
                        "Blocks": 0,
                        "Interceptions": 0,
                        "Duels Total": 1,
                        "Duels Won": 0,
                        "Dribble Attempts": 0,
                        "Dribble Successful": 0,
                        "Dribble Past": 0,
                        "Fouls Drawn": 0,   
                        "Fouls Committed": 0,
                        "Red Card": 0,
                        "Yellow Card": 0,
                        "Penalties Won":    0,
                        "Penalties Committed": 0,
                        "Penalties Scored": 0,
                        "Penalties Missed": 0,
                        "Penalties Saved": 0
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer.